# Will PowerPoint work with all the editing done in MS Office?

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

If we open a PowerPoint presentation in Ubuntu, will all the animations and transitions be working as before?

Comment: There is only one way to find that out. Open it in Ubuntu and see how it works. Then save it and open it in Windows again. Probably it will not be 100% the same.

Comment: There is no way to be sure whether each and every type of animation and transition will in a powerpoint will translate exactly the same way in LibreOffice. I am voting to close this question as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: @user68168 Wouldn't "too broad" be more appropriate here? Not tryin to be picky, just want to let op know the path to resolution in case he/she wants to fix the question. I usually reserve _opinion-based_ for "what's the best way" or "which is better" questions where the correct answer is impossible to determine, and any answer provided must depend on the answerer's opinion. Would you agree?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem worthwhile to install Microsoft Office in Ubuntu just to open one file that I can open online in Google Drive. Every PowerPoint presentation (.ppt/.pps/.pptx/.ppsx) that I ever got worked properly in LibreOffice Impress except for one fancy .pptx presentation that had audio and animations. Microsoft PowerPoint can save presentations in their own .ppt, .pps, pptx, and .ppsx formats, all of which can be uploaded to Google Drive, opened in Google Slides and then downloaded back down to your computer in the .odp format which is used by default to save presentations in Impress.

Comment: Doesnt Drive have a desktop app for Debian based systems? If so, It should let the user open docs via the interface, like on the web app. If so, that might as well be a desktop solution. The difference between web and native is slowly fading anyway. XD

Answer (score 2):

Try to export the PowerPoint to PDF first and then open the PDF in Ubuntu, because if you open a PowerPoint with Office, it will get deconstructed and weird.

Comment: Won't conversion to PDF loose all animations and transitions?

Comment: You don't lose anything if you first try it, but I bet yes, it will lose it... But try it